# how to maximize usage of number of databases on a postgres server while limited by connections

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sharding, connection-pooling

We're building a system where ideally we'd give a database per client in a multi-tenant setup.

However, although a single Postgres install supports 4,294,950,911 databases on a server, the suggested `max_connections` is around 100 or so.

That means if we used every active connection up to some recommended amount (using 100 as an example), we can at one time only access 0.000002 % of the available databases.

In no way would I need to utilize 4B databases, but would be great to utilize more than 100, certainly.

In looking up connection info in `pg_stat_activity`, seems that each connection includes a database name, so I'm guessing you cannot create a connection pool on the same server across different database names. I was hoping there would be a solution that allowed a connection pool across databases on the same server, finding that's not the case - please enlighten me if there is something in this realm of solutions.

So my options I believe at each end of the spectrum are:

1. shard tenants across schemas, and use connection pooling on same database
2. multiplex and/or context switch connections from the API server, using an LRU cache of pg pools that manage connections, closing the ones that the LRU cache disposes.

### question

Assuming I wanted to build 10,000 databases per database server, I'd look to get a solution like #2 working, to access different databases. How expensive it is really to open/close a connection if it happens quite often?

And if it's not feasible, is the number of databases allowed in postgres just a computer science theoretical number, that we'll only ever use a fraction of a fraction of a percent of? And in reality, we'd at best use a number of databases that correlates closely with the number of connections?

I'm also guessing there may be a hybrid solution that allows us to use many databases but minimize the connections per server with a fan-out using logical replication. But that sounds like it could get more expensive.

Comment: How many concurrent users do you expect? For all tenants?

Comment: I'm thinking around 10,000 tenants w burst traffic and each tenant having different levels and frequencies of activity. I have a server that keeps track of connections, and use an LRU to store pgpools... I suppose worst-cast during burst times each client request would require an opening and closing of a connection, and during other times there could be the most and recently visited dbs with cached connections in a pool.

Comment: The number of tenants is not relevant. The activity of the tenants is relevant. Pooling with multi tenants may be treated as ONE tenant. I use this to set the values: https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/